# Compare two table data and get list uncommon data

Tags: mysql

I have two table subscribers and charge

I am trying to get all subscribers list which not in charge table from previous two months.

I am new in sql don't know how can get this, I have tried below sql which not working

```
select * subscribers UNION select *from charge;
```

Table structure :
subscribers :

```
id || mobile|| subscribers_date
```

charge :

```
id || mobile || status || charge_date
```

my date field name is subscribers_date.

Comment: Share your table structures along with sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NOT IN operator.

```
Select * from subscribers where 
   mobile not in (select mobile from charge where charge_date > '2 months ago')
```

And your `charge` table needs a covering index on `charge_date, mobile`

Comment: It's working for small database , my table size is huge, so it is hanging.

Comment: Do you have index on subscribers_date, subscribers_id?

Comment: I have tried 

select * from subscribers wheresubscribers.id not in (select id from charges where d_date >= date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-01') - interval 2 month)

Comment: I see your problem. The join is not on an id, but the phonenumber. I will update the answer

Comment: I have tried it, same result. table made hang and it is loading and loading ...
select * from subscribers where subscribers.mobile not in (select mobile from charge where d_date >= date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-01') - interval 2 month)

Comment: Ok. You need to give me some numbers then. How many entries in subscribers? How many in mobile? How many in mobile that is younger than 2 months?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124763/discussion-between-satu-sultana-and-cine).